# Insert empty rows to columns to match empty rows in adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I am trying to match up data in three adjacent columns with data in a fourth column.

This is how my data is currently organized:

```
ROW   A     B     C
----------------------
1    Cat   Car    Red
2    Dog   Bike   Blue
3    Bird  Car    
4    Bear  Car    Blue
5    Fish  Bike   Red  
6    Cow   Car    Red
```

(the values in column A are unique; the values in B and C are repeated values)

And this is how I need it to be organized:

```
ROW   A     B     C
----------------------
1    Cat   Car    Red
2    Dog   Bike   Blue
3
4    Bird  Car    Blue
5    Bear  Car    Red
6    Fish  Bike   Red
```

Basically, I need columns A and B to see that column C is empty in row 3, and to insert blank cells in A3 and B3 so that each A and B value below that is moved down by one.

The spreadsheet has many of these needed insertions. Some of them will be individual insertions like the example above, but others might be 3, 4, 5, 10 insertions in a row.

Is there a formula or some kind of automated process I can use to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean if [C3] is empty then clear [A3] and [B3] content ? If then,maybe a macro is needed.

Comment: No; if C3 is empty, then push A3 and B3 down to the A4 and B4 positions.

Comment: Do the blank rows need to be in there? It would be a lot simpler to just remove the blank cells from column C and pull the data up rather than push the data in A and B down

Comment: Dan, yes, the blank rows do need to be there.

Answer (score 1):

From the example you posted, you want to push A and B down when C is blank?

```
Sub PushDown()
    Dim X As Long
    For X = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If IsEmpty(Range("C" & X)) Then Range("A" & X & ":B" & X).Insert xlDown
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this macro works when there is a single insertion, but when there are two insertions together, the blank cells are inserted above and below the adjacent cell. For example, if cell C2 in my example was also blank, the resulting column A would be Cat [blank] Dog [blank] Bird. The desired result would be Cat [blank] [blank] Dog Bird.

Comment: If it makes things easier, I wouldn't mind macro'ing each column separately. So... compare column A with column C, and then column B with column C.

Comment: Do the blank rows need to be in there? It would be a lot simpler to just remove the blank cells from column C and pull the data up rather than push the data in A and B down

Comment: Dan, thanks again for all your help. I got your script to work on a simple test spreadsheet, but when I try to apply it to my production spreadsheet, the macro does not run. this shows a screenshot of my production spreadsheet (http://snag.gy/poqSJ.jpg) and this shows my test worksheet before (successfully) running the macro (http://snag.gy/ezfXw.jpg). Any ideas on what would cause it to fail on the production sheet? I can supply the production sheet if that would help.

Comment: Probably the cell is not truly empty, change this If IsEmpty(Range("C" & X)) to this If trim(Range("C" & X)) = ""

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub clearContent()
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 4) = "" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3)).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a side note, use rows.count instead of 65536 in a .End and use Long instead of integer in VBA :). See my answer to this thread and the InsertRowsByQTY one we both answered for an example :)

Comment: Nice to meet you! You are right ! Is push down not clearcontent.

Comment: All good mate, nice to meet you too, I did like the fill down idea you used on the other one :)